# Unable to use the logical operator despite of casting in the written query using Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, presto, amazon-athena

I am unable to use a logical operator on one of my columns even though I'm casting it as a big int."total_submitted_charge amount" is stored as a string in my database.  Below is my query:

```
SELECT npi,
         provider_last_name,
         provider_first_name,
         provider_mid_initial,
         provider_address_1,
         provider_address_2,
         provider_city,
         provider_zipcode,
         provider_state_code,
         provider_country_code,
         provider_type,
         number_of_services,
         try_cast(CAST(REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount,
         ',') AS DECIMAL) AS BIGINT) AS total_submitted_amount
FROM cmsaggregatepayment2017
WHERE provider_zipcode='90250'
```

As soon as I add `" AND total_submitted_amount>2000"`, query stops working. Can someone please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per SQL spec, `total_submitted_amount` is a projection and can be used only in the "outer" scope. I.e. you can either

```
SELECT * FROM ( <your query> ) WHERE total_submitted_amount > 2000
```

or

```
< your query >
...  AND try_cast(CAST(REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount, ',') AS DECIMAL) AS BIGINT) > 2000
```

Note: there is no performance penalty from using the expression second time, it will still be evaluated once per row in Presto (Athena is based on Presto).